# What happens if a user does not have the Youtube app installed?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm starting android development and I'm looking into downloading and viewing video content. I know of the VideoView/MediaPlayer method and have just come across the YouTube API.

I noticed there is a small notice that says the user must have the YouTube app installed to use the API.

What will happen if such a user were to attempt to use the app? Will in crash? Will the video just not play? Will the user be prompted in any way to download the YouTube app, informing them of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user will be informed that they need the YouTube app in order for the app to work.  Then they will be given the chance to go install it.

That's about it...